# Install or Use App in my jailbroken ipodtouch

Tags: iphone

I developed an app for my own use.I want to use it on my ipodtouch.I jailbroke my device.But don't know how can i install my app in my device.Can any one give me proper instruction what should be the approach to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way of putting applications on to devices is to sign up to the [Apple Developer program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/).

I found [this link](http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?p=354) specifically for jailbroken devices, but it seems a bit dated.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to you iphone with [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) with username:root password:alpine or dottie. After that go to your Applications Folder on the device, make a new folder name (Whatever you want to call it).app then put all your files in that folder. Highlight them all, and set the permissions to 0755. Restart your phone. And thats it.